# How do I measure the execution time of a function in a linux binary executable?

Tags: linux, trace, perf

How do I measure the execution time of a function in a binary executable? I don't have source code, so I can't use -pg. What I can think of is perf, but looks like there is not way to show specific time spent on one function.

Comment: Does `perf report` give a result after acquisition runing your binary? It will display which percent of time is spent in functions, as long as the binary has debug symbols (not necessary for that to be built with -pg).

Comment: Yes, but there is only percentage time spent, not detailed enough for my purpose.

Comment: Can't you get the time knowing the global execution time of sampling? With the option `-n` of the command `report`, that shows `the number of samples for each symbol`, maybe it is easier to compute. Don't expect too much having only a binary and no source files.